# Why does the menu controller has to be the first responder in order to appear in the Window

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to iOS and I'm not clear why does it have to be the first in order.

Comment: Are you talking about root view controller of UIWindow in your App Delegate? We need some context or code.

Comment: No. I'm talking about UIMenuController. The following example of code is from a book:                                                -(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder                                      {                                                                  return YES;                                                              }

Comment: That doesn't say it HAS to be the first responder, that says it CAN become the first responder, to receive touch events and such: (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/canBecomeFirstResponder)